# Ruby Shoes won't start in Leopard

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-leopard, shoes

So I wanted to try doing some easy Ruby GUI programs using Ruby Shoes. I downloaded Shoes 3 for OS X, opened the dmg and installed it to the Applications folder. When I click on the icon in the folder, or drag a source code file to it, the icon briefly appears in the dock and bounces, and then disappears without anything running. So I can't use it. The computer I'm trying to run it on is running Leopard - is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried building shoes 4? You might want to check it out, and check the readme. I can confirm it working on my 10.6 mac, which is about as close to leopard as you can find. Just try the directions for *nix and it should work, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. While looking around for how to build Shoes 4, I found a place on the site where they said "we're looking for people who can build for Leopard, because we can't. Right now it only works on Snow Leopard and up." Oh well. It's a bit of a hassle to have to use it only on my Lion computer, but I can.

Comment: Ahh, well, at least it's close. Shoes, despite it's great funtionality, seems to be dying out.

Comment: we're trying hard to revive it :-)